# Obter o id do usuário logado de uma sessão do nodes.js

Tags: node.js, passport-js

Estou usando o passport com session e preciso obter o id do usuário de uma sessão. Tentei usar:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=' +  req.user.id, res);
})
```

Erro:

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: nao seria `req.params.id`? pelo que eu entendi voce esta passando o id pelo parametro da url.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de pegar pela sessão, tentei fazer utilizando o rarametro pela url mas não é viável para aplicação. Mas agradeço a correção na pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Se você quer pegar o id pela url é req.query.id
Mas eu utilizo com NoSQL, não sei se funciona com SQL. Vê se o express tem essa possibilidade para utilizar com SQL:
https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html